# How to change rows to columns in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

With the following code I want to change the rows to columns but I don't know how:

```
dataListStep = ld.loadData("../data/mpi/onlycsv/StepData")
indexStepData = 1
stepData = dataListStep[indexStepData]
resultsPerRowIndex = list()

for i in range(len(stepData)):
    stepDataLeft = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 0:5]
    stepDataRight = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 5:10]
    dataF = pd.DataFrame({'stepDataLeft': stepDataLeft, 'stepDataRight': stepDataRight}, index=['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean'])
    resultsPerRowIndex.append(sv.symmetryIndex(dataF.stepDataLeft, dataF.stepDataRight))
print(str(resultsPerRowIndex))
```

This is my output:

[image]

**EDIT**

I want to have an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't share code/data as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the result should be a dataframe, not a list:

```
#Declare the column names
columnNames = ['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean']
#Declare the result dataframe
resultsPerRowIndex =  pd.DataFrame(columns=columnNames )

for i in range(len(stepData)):
    stepDataLeft = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 0:5]
    stepDataRight = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 5:10]
    dataF = pd.DataFrame({'stepDataLeft': stepDataLeft, 'stepDataRight': stepDataRight}, index=columnNames)
    rowData = sv.symmetryIndex(dataF.stepDataLeft, dataF.stepDataRight)
    resultsPerRowIndex = resultsPerRowIndex.append(rowData, ignore_index=True)
print(str(resultsPerRowIndex))
```

Comment: Then I get the error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transpose'

Comment: Then you need to use it on a dataframe object, in this case dataF I think. I'm not entirely sure what you want to transpose

Comment: How can I use this on dataF? I want to have the names of the first column in my output as a row (table head).

Comment: resultsPerRowIndex is a list, each element of that list is whatever comes out of the function sv.symmetryIndex. What type of data is this? Is this what you want to transpose (i.e., transform rows into columns)?

Comment: So the transpose should be on the last line of the for loop, like this: `resultsPerRowIndex.append(sv.symmetryIndex(dataF.stepDataLeft, dataF.stepDataRight).transpose())`
Does this work?

Comment: `resultsPerRowIndex.append(sv.symmetryIndex(dataF.stepDataLeft, dataF.stepDataRight).transpose())` this do nothing

Comment: Do you have an other idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206458/discussion-between-3snow-and-mathflower).